# glSampleMask - can set, but how to get?

Tags: opengl

I can set the sample mask for multi-sampling in OpenGL with the following:

> void glSampleMaski(GLuint maskNumber, GLbitfield mask);

, [described here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glSampleMaski.xml). How can I get the current sample mask for mask number "n"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenGL specification states the following:

#### [OpenGL 4.4 Specfication](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf) - 17.3 Per-Fragment Operations - pp. 448

> SAMPLE_MASK_VALUE is queried by calling [`glGetIntegeri_v`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGet.xml) with target set to SAMPLE_MASK_VALUE and the index set to maskNumber.

So, in short:

```
glGetIntegeri_v (GL_SAMPLE_MASK_VALUE, mask_num, &mask);
```

Comment: Ah.  There it is.  Thanks very much Andon.

Comment: @Andon: Can you guys tell what does sample masking mean? What does mask number denote? I wanted to ask a separate question on this, but thought this will be a better place.